# Radius of convergence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)+11^n+6^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)+11^n+6^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$$

$y=x^2$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)+11^n+6^n}{(2n)!}y^{n}$$

$$R=lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\mid\frac{\sin (n)+11^n+6^n}{(2n)!}\mid}^{\frac{1}{n}}=lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\mid\frac{\sin (n)+11^n+6^n}{(2n)!}\mid^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

How do I find that the radius is $0$? is it because $2n!>>11^n$? isnt it $0^0$?

Comment: It converges everywhere, the radius of convergence is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to start simplifying.

For instance: the entire numerator is (strongly) dominated by just $11^n$; we can leverage this by writing
$$
\sin n+6^n+11^n=11^n\left(\frac{\sin n}{11^n}+\left(\frac{6}{11}\right)^n+1\right)
$$
and noting that the second term tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Now, using this, we can see that if $a_n$ is the coefficient by $x^{2n}$ above, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}x^{2n+2}}{a_nx^{2n}}\right\rvert&\overset{(\dagger)}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{11^{n+1}}{11^n}\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}\cdot x^2\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{11x^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
&=0
\end{align*}
$$
for absolutely any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ -- meaning that by comparison with a geometric series, this series converges absolutely for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. This is equivalent to saying that the radius of convergence is infinite.

Note that I've left out some details here -- particularly with the equality marked $(\dagger$).  But, you've got all the information you need to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Stirling's formula will help
$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n.$$
And yes, as @André Nicolas said, the radius of convergence is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)+11^n+6^n}{(2n)!}y^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n y^n.$$
As  @André Nicolas said, the [radius of convergence](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Radius_of_convergence) is infinite:
$$R=\lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{1}{11}\frac{\frac{\sin{n}}{11^n}+1+(\frac{6}{11})^n}{\frac{\sin{(n+1)}}{11^{n+1}}+1+(\frac{6}{11})^{n+1}}(2n+2)(2n+1)|=\infty.$$ 
Just to notice: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{1}{11}\frac{\frac{\sin{n}}{11^n}+1+(\frac{6}{11})^n}{\frac{\sin{(n+1)}}{11^{n+1}}+1+(\frac{6}{11})^{n+1}}|=\frac{1}{11}$$

Answer (score 1):

We can be reckless with our estimates:

$$\left | \frac{\sin (n)+11^n+6^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}\right | \le  \frac{3\cdot 11^n}{(2n)!}|x|^{2n}.$$

The ratio test shows the series of terms on the right converges for all $x.$ Thus $\sum \frac{\sin (n)+11^n+6^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$ converges absolutely for all $x.$ This implies the radius of convergence of this series is $\infty.$